# Basis change of matrices

Tags: python, combinations

I have tried to convert a combination of 5 elements with 50 numbers `list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 51), 5))` to two coordinates `[x, y]`. My goal is to put all probabilities into a grid and then randomize some combination to put them belonging its coordinates.

I think I need to make it using a basis change of matrices from `matrix(a, b, c, d, e)` to `matrix(x, y)`, but I didn't reach my goal.

Combinations will return something like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6
...
1, 2, 3, 4, 50
...
1, 2, 3, 5, 7
...
44, 46, 47, 48, 49
...
46, 47, 48, 49, 50
```

So I want to get a unique identifier for each combination, and then to transform this number to coordinates in a bidimensional matrix.

I think this is the simplest way.

Because my goal still the same thing: to represent all 2,118,750 combinations on a screen and then insert some random combinations to see how they occupy all the printable surface.

In other words: to make something like this page: http://lotterycodex.com/visual-analysis

Comment: You have not explained it clearly. The best way would be to create a small example, instead of 5 elements with 50 numbers try 3 elements with 5 numbers. Then by hand show us the exact output would want.

Comment: "I hope I explain it clearly" -- Alas, you did not. You have given no idea of how 5 numbers are supposed to map to 2, and the link with probability is obscure. A change of basis won't transform a 5-dimensional vector to a 2-dimensional one.

Comment: OK. (And sorry.)

Combinations will return something like:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 6
...
44, 46, 47, 48, 49
...
46, 47, 48, 49, 50

So I want to get a unique identifier for each combination, and then to transform this number to coordinates in a bidimensional matrix. I think this is the simplest way.

Because my goal still the same thing: to represent all 2,118,750 combinations on a screen and then insert some random combinations to see how they occupy all the printable surface.

In other words: to make something like this: https://lotterycodex.com/visual-analysis/

Comment: Please edit the question rather than add the clarification in the comments

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach:

```
import itertools

index = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(itertools.combinations(range(1,51),5))}

def f(c):
    return divmod(index[c],1456) #1456 = the ceiling of the square root of 2118750
```

For example,

```
>>> f((10,20,30,40,50))
(983, 913)
```

It is possible to compute the index of a combination directly by working out a rank function for the combinations, but it only takes a second or so to initialize the dictionary, so why bother?